# How to set different languages for locale format and Windows 7 programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, locale, regional-settings

I have Windows 7 SP1 x64 in English.

Under `Region and Language` I've set my locale Format to `Spanish (Argentina)` because I want to see dates and time in my country's format.

I don't like the programs being displayed in `Spanish (Argentina)`, I want them in `English (US)` just like Windows.

I've set `Language for non-Unicode programs` to `English (United States)`. Still some programs still show in Spanish. I think they're setting the language set in the Locale Format.

Is there a way to have all programs in `English (US)` while keeping my locale format in `Spanish (Argentina)`?

Comment: A program does not have to respect your region and language options. how a program implements its interface its entirely up to it, Windows does not have control, so your question is sort of broad since there isn't a universal answer to your question since there is no option that will force ALL programs to behave the same way.

Comment: I'm talking about programs that do rely on the Windows settings to set the language. Clearly the original language is English and it's showing in Spanish because of my Windows settings...

Comment: if it was clear I would have raised the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set your locale to US English and then change just the date/time settings.

Look in the Region section of Control Panel.

The default is for formats to match the locale but you can change the short/long date and time formats. Clicking on Additional Details gives you yet more control including number and currency settings.

Also, if you would like to *sometimes* use Spanish, clicking on the Language Preferences allows you to set up multiple languages you can switch between (at least it does on W8, not sure about W7 but I expect it to be the same).